# rewrite code in php

Tags: php

I have a problem with my client website.

my client website is `xyz.com/abc.php` but unfortunately one of our external link webmaster has given slash at the end of the url as `xyz.com/abc.php/`

now problem is google is reading text version pages of all the `abc.php` as duplicate content pages as cache text only version.

My webdeveloper has confirmed that these type of text version pages are not available in our root directory.

Then how google is creating new pages in text version and indexing.

is there is any problem in writing rewriting code?

Kindly help me out/

Comment: I'm not 100% with you... the english needs to be improved a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like Google is indexing multiple copies of your content with slightly different URLs. If this is the case, then common SEO wisdom stipulates that duplicative content on a site does not help search engine page rank.

I would recommend using Apache URL rewriting to issue HTTP 301 Moved Permanently redirects for problem URLs, effectively telling search engines that the content is no longer available at problem URLs and that such URLs should not be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

could it be to do with relative linking to the css

ie **xyz.com/layout.css** and xyz.com/abc.php/layout.css

if you are linking to the css using just the relative link **layout.css** then it will add after the **abc.php/** (xyz.com/abc.php/layout.css). whereas if you use **/layout.css** it'll go to the root url **xyz.com** then add **/layout.css** (xyz.com/layout.css).

alternatively put all css etc. links in as absolute **http:// www.xyz.com/layout.css**

hope that makes sense and helps